# deducing irreducibility from intersections with hyperplane complements

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Suppose that for any hyperplane complement $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, $X \cap U$ is irreducible.
Then i want to prove that $X$ must be irreducible.

Here is how i go about it: Suppose $X=Y \cup Z$, where $Y,Z$ are closed 
subsets of $X$. Then for any hyperplane complement $U$ we have that
either $X \cap U = Y \cap U$ or $X \cap U = Z \cap U$. Since there are 
infinitely many hyperplane complements, we can assume without loss of 
generality that $X \cap U_i = Y \cap U_i$ for $i=0,\dots,n$ complements
of hyperplanes in general position. Then we can define an automorphism $\phi$
of $\mathbb{P}^n$ that sends $U_i$ to the standard affine open $z_i \neq 0$.
Then we will have that $\phi(X)  = \phi(Y)$ and so $X=Y$.

**Question:** As far as i can see my argument seems correct. Is this the standard way of proving this result?